Scraping formulario dinámico Javascript
Estoy intentando scrapear un formulario en Javascript, y me surge un problema. En el campo "género" si selecciono "mujer", todo funciona correctamente, pero si selecciono el campo "hombre" no puedo seleccionar el campo "prueba" por lo que se me rompe el código y no puedo continuar. Los demás campos, los puedo seleccionar todos, pero si no selecciono la prueba, no me aparece el ranking.
Copio el código:


const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Función para esperar un tiempo aleatorio entre min y max milisegundos
function randomTimeout(min, max) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min));
}

// Función para realizar el scraping de un año específico
async function scrapeYear(page, year, isFirstIteration) {
    await page.goto('https://atletismorfea.es/ranking/');  // Navegar a la URL de nuevo para reiniciar el estado

    if (isFirstIteration) {
        // Aceptar cookies solo en la primera iteración
        await page.waitForSelector('#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll');
        await page.click('#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll');
        await randomTimeout(2000, 5000);
    }

    // Hacer clic en el radio button "Pista aire libre"
    await page.waitForSelector('label[for="edit-style-al"]');
    await page.click('label[for="edit-style-al"]');
    await randomTimeout(2000, 5000);

    // Seleccionar el género
    await page.waitForSelector('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-gender"]');
    await page.select('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-gender"]', '1');
    await randomTimeout(7000, 9000);

    // Seleccionar el año
    await page.waitForSelector('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-season"]');
    await page.select('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-season"]', year.toString());
    await randomTimeout(2000, 5000);

    // Seleccionar la prueba
    await page.waitForSelector('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-type"]');
    await page.select('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-type"]', '4');
    await randomTimeout(5000, 9000);

    // Seleccionar la prueba (100m) después de todo lo demás
    await page.waitForSelector('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-event"]');
    await page.select('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-event"]', 'a1v7Q000000twigQAA');
    await randomTimeout(2000, 5000);

    // Ver ranking
    await page.waitForSelector('#edit-button');
    await page.click('#edit-button');
    console.log(`Botón "Ver ranking" clicado usando ID para el año ${year}`);
    await randomTimeout(8000, 10000);

    // Mostrar todas las marcas
    await page.waitForSelector('select[title="cantidad a mostrar"]');
    await page.select('select[title="cantidad a mostrar"]', '100');
    console.log('Opción "Todas" seleccionada en cantidad a mostrar');
    await randomTimeout(12000, 15000);

    // Esperar a que la tabla esté disponible en la página
    await page.waitForSelector('.tabla_ranking');
    console.log('Tabla de ranking encontrada');

    // Bucle para hacer clic en el botón "Ver más" hasta que ya no aparezca
    while (true) {
        const moreButton = await page.$('.ranking-pager-link');
        if (moreButton) {
            await moreButton.click();
            console.log('Botón "Ver más" clicado');
            // Esperar a que se carguen más resultados
            await randomTimeout(15000, 20000);
        } else {
            console.log('No se encontró el botón "Ver más", saliendo del bucle');
            break;
        }
    }

    // Extraer los datos de la tabla
    const tableData = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tabla_ranking tr'));
        return rows.map(row => {
            const cells = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('th, td'));
            return cells.map(cell => cell.innerText);
        });
    });

    // Convertir los datos de la tabla a CSV
    const csvContent = tableData.map(row => row.join(',')).join('\n');

    // Verificar y crear el directorio si no existe
    const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, 'csv');
    if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dirPath, { recursive: true });
    }

    // Guardar los datos de la tabla en un archivo CSV
    const filePath = path.join(dirPath, `prueba_400_H_${year}.csv`);
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, csvContent);
    console.log(`Datos de la tabla guardados en prueba_400_H_${year}.csv`);

    return tableData;
}

// Función principal para realizar el scraping
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,  // Lanzar Puppeteer en modo no headless para ver las acciones
        args: ['--window-size=1280,720']
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720 });

    let allData = [];  // Para almacenar todos los datos de todos los años

    for (let year = 2005; year <= 2023; year++) {
        const isFirstIteration = (year === 2005);
        const yearData = await scrapeYear(page, year, isFirstIteration);
        allData.push(...yearData);
    }

    // Convertir todos los datos a CSV
    const allCsvContent = allData.map(row => row.join(',')).join('\n');

    // Guardar todos los datos en un archivo CSV final
    const allFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'csv', 'prueba_400_H_all_years.csv');
    fs.writeFileSync(allFilePath, allCsvContent);
    console.log('Datos de la tabla guardados en prueba_400_H_all_years.csv');

    // Cerrar el navegador
    await browser.close();
})();



El código hace un recorrido por todos los años. Voy seleccionando las opciones que quiero, pero justo cuando selecciono el campo hombres, me da problemas en el campo anteriormente mencionado. Podéis probarlo y seleccionar "mujeres" en vez de hombres, y veréis a lo que me refiero, por si no me he explicado correctamente
Saludos y muchas gracias!

Podéis probarlo y seleccionar "mujeres" en vez de hombres, en donde pruebo eso?

Donde pone el comentario //Seleccionar el género Cambia el 1 final por un 2, que es el código para las mujeres. Y debería funcionar todo

Pasa que hay una solicitud ajax cuando cambias el select. Yo, en tu caso tomaría un camino completamente diferente. Entra a esta URL https://atletismorfea.es/ranking/2024/145/0/1/2/0/0/0/0/10/1 abre la consola y pega el siguiente código: ;document.body.innerHTML = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("textarea").value)[1].data;

¿Y de como se forma esa url? -> https://i.sstatic.net/VC7TV8at.png

Uf!! Ahí lo que pasa, por lo que veo en tu código, es todo javascript. Yo iba haciendo con puppeteer y un poco de chatGPT, que me ayudaba, porque de javascript controlo muy poco. Hago bastante scraping con python, pero de javascript ando muy perdido.

Porque en esta página, sí o sí hay que hacerlo con javascript, no?

Te explico mejor el asunto: Tu problema es que cuando se cambia el select, la página hace una llamada ajax para refrescar los campos, lo que debes hacer es esperar que esa llamada finalice y proseguir con tu código, yo no conozco puppeteer, pero generalmente lo que se hace es interceptar estos envíos fetch.

Por otro lado, tienes otra opción totalmente distinta, que es cargar la página directamente. Esta página retorna un textarea con un json dentro. Esa url se forma a partir de los campos del formulario, la foto que te puse no es mi código es el código de esa web, y te lo puse para que vieras como se forma la url

Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Ahora por lo menos sé por dónde van los tiros y dónde está el problema. Intentaré averiguar lo que me dices, pero me cuesta un poco jeje. Pero bueno, iré investigando. Lo dicho, muchas gracias!

Una mala solución seria crear una función delay, algo como function delay(ms) {   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));  } Entonces luego del await page.select(... pones await delay(3000) así das tiempo a que los campos se carguen
